# how to switch twig classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twig

I would like to switch a class when I click on a div.

```
    {{ form_row(onboardingChoicesChild.children.0, {'label_attr':
{'class':'textselection'}}) }}
```

The following form_row has a class "textselection", and I would like to toggle it. I know how to toggle class in javascript with div but I don't know how to toggle these datas.

Answer (score 0):

Twig is just making templating,

In your example, when you write `$(this).hasClass('selected')` you try to check if `<div class="selection">` has 'selected' class

In my opinion you should try this:

```
 if ($(this).first().hasClass('selected')) {
    $(this).first().removeClass('selected');
 } 
 else {
    $(this).first().addClass('selected');   
 }
```

Comment: The selection div toggling is already working. What I would like to do is switch the textselection from the form_row